# how to change the default video buffer size in Android

Tags: android, stagefright

I have found that the default video buffer size was set to 8 seconds in Gingerbread, so any clips shorter than this could not be played.

Is there any way to change default buffer size on streaming MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not API support to do this. Soz.

All you can do is monitor how much of the buffer is filled.

---

Since you are doing this by yourself, change this:

```
   static int64_t kHighWaterMarkUs = 10000000ll;  // 10secs
```

It is the buffering time, and this :

```
  static const size_t kHighWaterMarkBytes = 200000;
```

Comment: i am building the android source code to fix this issue. Which file do i need to  change it . i have checked Awesomeplayer.cpp